# Candlestick data in list to matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have got some candlestick data stored in list ( datetime, open, close, high, low) .
What would be the best way to plot this data using matplotlib ? Do I automatically have to go through numpy ? In which case how would I convert a list to something numpy understands ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Have you tried just feeding your list to the plotting routine? If that fails somehow, would you post the code which fails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, there's no reason to do anything other than what you already have. Matplotlib will handle converting things for you.

It sounds like you have a list of sequences of time, open, close, high low?

Something like:

```
from datetime import datetime
#            date                 open   close    high    low
quotes = [(datetime(2012, 2, 1), 103.62, 102.01, 103.62, 101.90),
          (datetime(2012, 2, 2), 102.24, 102.90, 103.16, 102.09),
          ...
          (datetime(2012, 4, 12), 100.89, 102.59, 102.86, 100.51)]
```

That's actually the exact data structure that matplotlib's candlestick function expects.

You just need to convert the datetimes to matplotlib's internal date format.  Use `matplotlib.dates.date2num`.

E.g.

```
from matplotlib.dates import date2num

# I'm assuming you have tuples, so we can't modify them in-place...
quotes = [(date2num(item[0]),) + item[1:] for item in quotes]
```

Other than that, have a look at some of the matplotlib finance examples. [This one is a good start.](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/finance_demo.html)

Comment: Wow! I did not realize matplotlib could plot candlesticks data. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily convert a python list to a numpy list

```
import numpy as np
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a = np.array(l1)
```

although matplotlib accepts python lists as well (I think it internally converts it to numpy arrays)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itemgetter`

```
from operator import itemgetter
data = [(1,2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4,5)]

import pylab as plt
plt.plot(map(itemgetter(0), data),map(itemgetter(1),data),'o')
```

In case you have multiple plots (where you plot the high, low, difference of high and low, etc. against the datetime data) it might be better to convert it to numpy array, as @Spot have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do it is to plot all this data a in one graph, so you can see the relative relationship. You can plot multiple lines in a graph this way:

```
import pylab

data = [(5,2,3), (2,8,4), (3,5,9)]
t_data = zip(*data) #transform the data

crd = range(len(t_data[0])) #coordinates

pylab.plot(crd, t_data[0], crd, t_data[1], crd, t_data[2])

pylab.show()
```

But if you wanted to print each category in a different graph, you could do:

```
fig = pylab.figure()

sub_fig_1 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,1)
sub_fig_1.plot(t_data[0])

sub_fig_2 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,2)
sub_fig_2.plot(t_data[1])

sub_fig_3 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,3)
sub_fig_3.plot(t_data[2])

pylab.show()
```